# Carousel Twitter BootStrap how to hide the previous or next button at the last and first Item

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to hide the previous button on the first item, and hide the right button when the carousel on the last item.
I know there is other same questions as mine but I really really cound't make it work, if someone can help and explain to me how it works for caroussel bootstrap i'll be really gratefull Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is my slider it's a tabed slider : http://codepen.io/hafsadanguir/pen/ZONxvV

```
 (function($) {

     $(document).ready( function() {
     $('#myCarousel').carousel({
      pause: true,
      interval: false
    });

  $(".prev-slide").click(function(){
         $("#myCarousel").carousel('prev');
     });
  $(".next-slide").click(function(){
      $("#myCarousel").carousel('next');
  });


  var clickEvent = false;
  $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
          clickEvent = true;
          $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
          $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
      if(!clickEvent) {
          var count = $('.nav li').length -1;
          var current = $('.nav li.active');
          current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
          var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to')) +1;
          if(count+1 == id) {
              $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');
          }
      }
    });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: why would you need to hide the next/previous button? In that case, are you sure that a carousel is what you really need?

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear I edit it

Answer (score 1):

1. You can change the display property of a control by [the `.css()` method](https://api.jquery.com/css/).
2. Use [the `slid.bs.carousel` event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events) to hide an arrow. If an item has the `.active` class at this point, it means that the item has just become active.

   > This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.
3. Use [the `slide.bs.carousel` event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events) to show an arrow. If an item has the `.active` class at this moment, it means that the item becomes inactive right now.

   > This event fires immediately when the slide instance method is invoked.

Please check the result. Is it what you want to achieve?

http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/EgawBK

```js
var myCarousel   = $('#myCarousel');
var itemFirst    = myCarousel.find('.carousel-inner > .item:first-child');
var itemLast     = myCarousel.find('.carousel-inner > .item:last-child');
var controlLeft  = myCarousel.find('a.left.carousel-control');
var controlRight = myCarousel.find('a.right.carousel-control');

hideControl();

myCarousel.on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
  hideControl(); 
});
myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
  showControl(); 
});

function hideControl() {
  if ( itemFirst.hasClass('active') ) {
    controlLeft.css('display', 'none');
  }
  if ( itemLast.hasClass('active') ) {
    controlRight.css('display', 'none');
    myCarousel.carousel('pause');  // stop from cycling through items
  } 
}

function showControl() {
  if ( itemFirst.hasClass('active') ) {
    controlLeft.css('display', 'block');
  }
  if ( itemLast.hasClass('active') ) {
    controlRight.css('display', 'block');
  }
}
```

```css
/* Make the images wide and responsive. */
.carousel-inner img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=Only%20Forward" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=Both%20Directions" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=Only%20Back" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, buddy!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.carousel-control {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look in the html.

Do `ctrl` + `f` on your html file.

And type in next or previous. You will see the next and previous classes stand.
Just remove them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I'm sorry I edit my question